# MongoDB mock returning null from

Tags: mongodb, junit5

I am running test case with SpringRunner and using MockBean for finding doc

My test case following code -

```
List<SomeClass> dummySomeClassList = Arrays.asList(new SomeClass("1", "example"), new SomeClass("2", "example2"));
@MockBean
private FindCollectionDocument findCollectionDocument;
```

When I use the following its not returning list instead its null

```
Mockito.when(findCollectionDocument.findCollection(Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class))).thenReturn(dummySomeClassList());
```

Actual class has following code -

```
List<SomeClass> someClassList = findCollectionDocument.findCollection(someClassObject);
```

Expecting my code to return someClassList  which is assigned in the test class, but its not returning anything and is blank.
How to get the dummySomeClassList(from test class) returned in the main class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use any mocks as `findCollection()` method argument, use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers` instead:

```
Mockito.when(findCollectionDocument.findCollection(any(SomeClass.class)))
                                    .thenReturn(dummySomeClassList)
```

So, with this line you say: when the `findCollection()` method with any argument of type `SomeClass` is called on my mock object `findCollectionDocument`, then return `dummySomeClassList`.

In your version you say: when the `findCollection()` method with argument `Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class)` is called on my mock object `findCollectionDocument`, then return `dummySomeClassList`. And during the test, `findCollection()` method isn't called with such an argument, therefore the default value for mock non-void methods is returned, i.e. `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your response !

I also have one more question regarding mocking constructor initialized class - 
In my class i have private variable of the class 

private someClass2;

and its returning map with constructor initialization 

seqTransformer = new someClass2(someThing);
collectionMap = seqTransformer.getCollectionMap(someThing);

how to mock collectionMap which is being returned please ?

Comment: It's hard to say without a snippet of code, but it seems like you can mock `seqTransformer` and then set the return map.

Comment: thank you, I have added the code snippet for your reference, please let me know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

My main class has the following code

```
Class ExampleA implements A{
private Map<String, Object> exMap;
 
@Override
pubic void doSomeThing1(){
// Method will set the exMap value
doSomeThing2(exMap.get(someClassObj))
}
@Override
pubic void doSomeThing2(SomeClass obj){
// Method will get and use exMap value for further processing
    }
}
```

I am writing the junit test case for doSomething2 and I am trying to mock that map that I get from doSomething1 and use that map in doSomething2

```
Mockito.when(exMap.get("sequenceInformation")).thenReturn((SomeClass)exMap.get("someClass"));
```

but it doesn't return anything, how to mock that map in doSomething2 method which i got from doSomething1 method ?